# Items measured with 5 and 7 point Likert scale in PLS-SEM analysis

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, likert, partial-least-squares

Some items in the questionnaire were measured with the 7-point Likert scale and some with the 5-point one. I am doing PLS-SEM analysis of the data in SmartPLS. Are there any additional steps to take to account for this difference?